# i'm on vb6, i need to set a get with https://oauth.openapi.it/counters/total

Tags: vba, api, rest, vb6, openapi

I use for all my get rest API this code in vb6:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub RestExample()

Dim APICall As String
Dim myXML As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

APICall = "http://www.zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", APICall, False
    .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"
    .send
    Debug.Print .responseText
End With

End Sub
```

how to set this code for this curl:

```
https://oauth.openapi.it/counters/total
```

note:
I just have email address and APIkey
the scope service is: `imprese.openapi.it`

Comment: `APICall = "https://oauth.openapi.it/counters/total"`?

Comment: You need to be more explicit about the *specific problem* you're having...

Comment: see here: https://developers.openapi.it/services/oauth#/counters/get_counters_total

Comment: I agree, its not clear what you are asking. Please edit your question to add information.